# Python character to keyboard hex

Tags: python, keyboard, hex

I would like to know how to change a keyboard key's character to it's hex value.
For example:

Key A: 0x41

Key B: 0x42

Key P: 0x80

Key Z: 0x5A

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00000520.html

The link above also has a list of the base 10 numbers for each key code, but I need those base 10 numbers converted to hex. Is there any easy way to just do something like this?

```
>>> toHex("b")
0x42
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `hex` together with `ord`:

```
>>> hex(ord("B"))
'0x42'
```

Answer (score 2):

you can get the ascii value of any character with ord

```
ord("B")
```

you can convert any number to hex representation with `hex`

```
hex(77)
```